# Rails collection_select default option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections

so I'm putting together a collection select.

```
<%= collection_select :PriceRange, "7", PriceRange.where('value > 0'), :value, :name %>
```

I'm trying to get the default selection to be PriceRange with the id of 7, this is independent and doesn't rely on any of the users settings, its part of a form that changes the items displayed on the page by their price range.

```
* * * UPDATED EFFORTS * * *
```

I added

```
@price_higher = PriceRange.find(7)
```

to the Controller that handles the view, and added

```
, {:selected => @price_higher.value}
```

inside the collection_select. It seems to do the trick, although was looking for a less complicated way of doing it all inside the collection_select.

Answer (score 47):

Add the `:selected` option.

Example:

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, {:selected => "whatever_value"})
```

Example took from: [ApiDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)

In your case:

```
<%= collection_select :PriceRange, "7", PriceRange.where('value > 0'), :value, :name, {:selected => "whatever"} %>
```

Comment: the reason I'm avoiding that is that the value may change down the road, and I'm trying to limit extra code that needs to be updated in the future, I also what to avoid something breaking if that item gets changed in the database and doesn't get updated on the view.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select a default value from data base then use,

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, {:selected => @authors.first})
```

---

If you want to prompt a message then use,

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, {:prompt => "Select Post"})
```

Comment: Why are you posting same answer provided by someone else?

Comment: Here no one posted the answer using :prompt, instead everyone used :selected. I combined my answer with other's answers also. Which gives more specific answer.

Comment: Well you are right but it is additional information which could be added as a comment in earlier answers. If everyone intend to do same for small update/improvement, edits will not take place for answer & large numbers of same answers will be present which will confuse readers.

Comment: Have a example here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54395303/10522579. Improvement is quite good choice.

Comment: yes, you are right but i am unable to comment on other's answers. When I am trying to add a comment, it says "You need 50 reputations to add comment". That was my problem. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, {:selected => @authors.first})
```

This ensures the values is always from the DB where the data is fetched and can change if the DB changes.

Comment: This ensures the values is always from the DB where the data is fetched and can change if the DB changes.